# Выполнение метода перед сменой endpoint

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

У меня есть `<router-link to='/my-endpoint'>`. Я хочу перед тем как перейти по этому endpoint выполнить метод. Сейчас я пытаюсь приспособить для этого `<router-link to='/my-endpoint' v-on:click.native="myMethod">`, но, я не совсем понимаю, как он работает. Я так понимаю, что он может отработать не полностью, если изменение endpoint произойдёт раньше. Мне же нужно, чтобы метод отработал полностью для того, чтобы `action` был точно дёрнут. Как это сделать?

`myMethod` Дёргает `action` `vuex` и делает запрос к API.

У меня есть ещё один вариант. Не использовать метод, а передать параметры в качестве `queryParams` и уже после редиректа вызвать метод, в новом компоненте. Но я не хочу использовать `queryParams, так как такой подход осложнит тестирование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [навигационные хуки](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4n%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

К примеру, используя навигационный хук ухода со страницы вызовем подтверждение действия:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Вы хотите уйти? У вас есть несохранённые изменения!')
  if (answer) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно повесить хук на конкретный редирект.

Comment: Используйте параметр `from` или `to`, сравнивайте с нужным роутом через `$route.path`

Comment: Решил проблему иначе. Сделал кастомный тег, у которого указал в явном виде сменить путь через соотв. событие

Comment: Для того, чтобы при наведении на объект оставался соответствующий курсор, я поправил стиль, указав `pointer`